# Выпадает символ при чтении параметра JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой вот участок кода, который читае полученные AJAX данный в JSON формате(лишний код убран):

```
function load_data_to_table(table, data, fields, add_data, button_del) {
    $.each(data, function (key,value) {
        console.log(value['fields']);
        $.each(fields, function (index,field) {
            console.log(field);
            console.log(value['fields'][field]);
    });
}
```

На первой итерации console.log выдаёт следующее:

```
{nds_procents: {…}, id: {…}, name: {…}, is_archive: {…}}
```

На второй, которая вводит имя поля:

```
nd_procents
```

пропадает один символ s. Его позиция не принципиально. он точно так же выпадает, если идёт первым или последним. Важно, что выпадает первый встречающийся в строке символ s
На третей, естественно, получаем:

```
undefined
```

Собственно у меня вопрос, а что это было? Почему такое происходит?
До each с переменной всё хорошо, но после первого же прохода цикла значение меняется..

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос снимается. Косяк был в массиве fields, именно там параметр был с отсутствующей s и в итоге не мог найти необходимsет данные в JSON.
Блин, день на смарку из-за ерунды